# Finding $A^{-3}$ using Cayley Hamilton Theorem

Tags: matrices, inverse, cayley-hamilton

> If $$A =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 4 \\
> 1 & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix},
> $$
>   then use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to find $A^{-3}$.

This is how far I have gotten:
\begin{align}
p(\lambda) &= \lambda^2 -3\lambda -2  \\
p(A) &= 0 = A^2-3A-2I  \\
A^2 &= 3A + 2I  \\
A^3 &= 3A^2 + 2A = 11A+6I
\end{align}

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $(2-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-4=2-\lambda -2\lambda +\lambda^2 -4=\lambda^2-3\lambda -2$.

CH ensures you that 
$$
A^2 - 3A = +2I
$$
hence 
$$
A(A-3I)=2I \qquad (A-3I)A = 2I
$$
so that $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(A-3I)$. From the equation above we also have, as you found,
$$
A^3 = 3A^2 +2A = 3(3A+2I) + 2A= 11A+6I.
$$
All in all, 
$$
A^{-3} = (A^{-1})^3 = \frac{1}{8}(A-3I)^3 = 8^{-1}(A^3 - 9A^2 + 27A - 27I)
$$
which can be further simplified into
$$
= 8^{-1}(11A+6I - 9(3A+2I)+27A-27I) = 
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{8}(11A+6I-27A -18 I +27A - 27I) = \frac{1}{8}(11A -39I)
$$
thus 
$$
\boxed{A^{-3} = \frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix}
-17 & 44 \\
11 & -28 
\end{bmatrix}}.
$$

Comment: @Rócherz Gosh what a shame :-)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Now go the other way around:
\begin{align}
p(\lambda) &= \lambda^2 -3\lambda -2  \\
p(A) &= O = A^2-3A-2I  \\
I &= A \color{blue}{A^{-1}} = \tfrac12A^2 -\tfrac32 A = A \color{blue}{(\tfrac12 A -\tfrac32 I)} \\
A^{-1} &= \tfrac12 A -\tfrac32 I 
\end{align}
Then $A^{-3}$ is just $A^{-1}$ times $A^{-1}$ times $A^{-1}$. You can reduce powers of $A$ using $p(A)$ if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells you that $A^2-3A-2I=0$; multiply by $A^{-1}$ to find
$$
2A^{-1}=A-3I
$$
Multiply again by $2A^{-1}$:
$$
4A^{-2}=2I-6A^{-1}=2I-3(A-3I)=11I-3A
$$
Multiply again by $2A^{-1}$:
$$
8A^{-3}=22A^{-1}-6I=11(A-3I)-6I=11A-39I
$$
In a different way, you know from CH that $A^{-3}=\alpha A+\beta I$; then
$$
I=\alpha A^4+\beta A^3
$$
and you can use CH for reducing the expression on the right.